# Formatting a text file in python

Tags: arcpy

This is my code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Brett\Desktop\lesson_6\Lesson6_Data"
infc = "Cities.shp"

outputFile =   open("C:\Users\Brett\Desktop\lesson_6\Lesson6_Data\Output_Cities1.txt", "w")      

arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

fc = "Cities.shp"
fields = ["NAME","SHAPE@XY"]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    outputFile.write('{0}, {1}'.format(row[0],(row[1])))

print "done"
```

This is what the outputted format looks like:

Hiawatha, (-1050316.3479999993, 2067521.4093999993)Powder Wash, (-1025371.6007000003, 2059421.7783000004)Kings Canyon, (-852695.0120999999, 2036738.5595999993)Columbine, (-915047.0152000003, 2035509.35099999

But I want it to look like this:

```
FredRanch1_1, 529018.125025, 4108038.05548
FredRanch1_1, 529005.718792, 4108028.20659
FredRanch1_1, 528993.340503, 4108018.73931
FredRanch1_1, 528980.990158, 4108009.65364
FredRanch1_1, 528968.667757, 4108000.94958
```

etc....

Any suggestions on how to format is correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`SHAPE@XY` returns a tuple of values, which you can access by their index position. You can add line breaks for each record by adding `\n` to the end of the line.

```
for row in cursor:
    outputFile.write('{0}, {1}, {2}\n'.format(row[0], row[1][0], row[1][1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

this helped me have it in rows

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
COFile.write(u'{0}, {1}'.format(row[0], row[1])+ "\n")
COFile.close()
print("done")

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.